# jQuery click div inside a tag

Tags: jquery, html

My HTML

```
<ul class="hotels-list clearfix">
     <li class="hotels-list-item clearfix">
         <a href="">
              <div class="btn-forward forward"></div>
              <div class="btn-back back"></div>
         </a>
      </li>
</ul>
```

Is there any way to click `div` inside `a` tag without click on parent `a` tag ?

I tried to use code bolow but it doesn't work

```
$back = $(this).find('a.back'),
$forward = $(this).find('a.forward');

$back.click(function (e) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return gotoPage(currentPage - 1);
                });

                $forward.click(function (e) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return gotoPage(currentPage + 1);
                });
```

Comment: It's semantically incorrect to nest a div within an anchor tag.

Comment: If you aren't going to use the `<a />` element, why not just remove it? You can always replace it with something that doesn't do anything when clicked, i.e. another Div

Comment: You can't find `a.back` in this code, because it's not an `<a>` it's a `div`!! Just try to find `.back` and `.forward`..

Comment: you should use the new syntax event : `$back.on("click", function(e){})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your selector are wrong, use

```
$back = $(this).find('a .back'),
$forward = $(this).find('a .forward');
```

Comment: That's what i said also, but okay ;) +1

Comment: your comment wasn't appear when I post, sorry ^^

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul class="hotels-list clearfix">
     <li class="hotels-list-item clearfix">
              <div class="btn-forward forward"></div>
              <div class="btn-back back"></div>
      </li>
</ul>

$back = $(this).find('.back'),
$forward = $(this).find('.forward');

$back.click(function (e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
     e.preventDefault();
     return gotoPage(currentPage - 1);
});

$forward.click(function (e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
     e.preventDefault();
     return gotoPage(currentPage + 1);
});
```

This is kind of the summary of all comments :)